# MongoDB Fixed size collection with no race condition

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Say that I want to limit the number of documents in my collection to be no more than 10. I can check the document count before inserting a new document. That's fine, but there could be simultaneous requests where count is found to be < 10. This would result in more than 10 documents ending up in the collection.

How can I prevent this?

I can't use capped collections because I need to explicitly control which documents are removed and when.

It is implemented in NodeJs running on ECS on multiple nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Write your queries to sort the collection and retrieve the 10 documents you want. For example, if you want 10 most recent documents sort by modification time and get the last 10. This way you can have more than 10 in the collection but when you query your result set would match your requirements.